# css aligning of floating images

Tags: html, css

This is an example of the problem  http://jsfiddle.net/nggrj1zt/4/  .
The images and captions are being randomly generated so cannot apply style individually

this is the html

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div class="specialsticky">
      <img src="img1" alt="first image">
      <div class="mast-screen" style="opacity: 0.5;"></div>
      <div class="mast-screen1">
         <h1 class="mast-header"><a href="#">This the title </a></h1>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div style="clear:both"></div>


   <div class="specialsticky">
      <img src="img2" alt="second image"> 
      <div class="mast-screen" style="opacity: 0.5;"></div>
      <div class="mast-screen1">
        <h1 class="mast-header"><a href="#">This the title </a></h1>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div style="clear:both"></div>

   <div class="specialsticky">
      <img src="img3" alt="third image">
      <div class="mast-screen" style="opacity: 0.5;"></div>
      <div class="mast-screen1">
      <h1 class="mast-header"><a href="#">This the title </a></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

The images are aligned but the captions and mastheads need to be aligned to their respective images. When I tried using relative positioning, the alignment of the images gets disrupted.

Comment: How do you want them aligned? What is your desired output?

Comment: the images are aligned properly.But,I want the individual captions to be over the image and with that opaque background behind it.

Comment: How do you want the captions aligned

Comment: the alignment should be similar to that provided by @misterManSam.But,I wanted to access all the three captions individually so I can fix their heights according to image size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `position:relative` to `.specialsticky`. Currently `.mast-screen` and `.mast-screen1` are being positioned relative to the viewport.

[Have an example!](http://jsbin.com/hecope/1/edit)

CSS

```
.specialsticky {
    position: relative;
}
```

[Here is a simplified example](http://jsbin.com/pavuh/1/edit) with percentage heights and transition hover states.

Comment: Can the height of individual caption and background be changed according to the height of the image?

Comment: Yes, with percentages. [Here is an example](http://jsbin.com/pavuh/1/edit) - I have also simplified the CSS and HTML, check it out :)